# Mongoose change date based on another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so here is my problem. I am writting an app, course app and I have hit a wall. My problem is that, whenever user adds new course to database it automatically set up two field called `startingDate` and `nextClasses`. At the beginning `nextClasses` field is equal to `startingDate` but I'd like to periodically change that date every week. So for example classes starts at 11th of January and during night between sunday and monday date updates itself to 18th on every document. My problem is that I have no idea how can I write my `updateMany` code to change those values. I know that I have to use some library to update that date like `nodejs cron` but can't figure out how should `updateMany` look like.

Here is my `courseModel`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
        // required: true,
        owner: {
            name: String,
            email: String
        }
    },
    startingDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    nextClasses: {
        type: Date
    },
    students: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        }
    ]
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);

module.exports = Course;
```

And my route to update data which does not work.

```
router.patch('/course/updateTime',async(req,res) => {
    try {

        const data = await Course.updateMany({"nextClasses": whatShouldIPutHere},
            { $set: {"nextClasses": new Date() }});
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

I understand how `updateMany` works and what paramethers I should pass but I have no idea how to pass value from another field to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my problem. Additional condition to check which date take under consideration :)

```
const courses = await Course.find({});
            courses.forEach(course => {
                Course.updateMany({"nextClasses": course.nextClasses === course.startingDate ? course.startingDate : course.nextClasses},
                    {$set: {"nextClasses": new Date()}},(err) => console.log(course.nextClasses)
                )
            });
```